# Transmission cannot connect to tracker

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

I installed the software trasmission, but I can't set it up. The following lines, are copied from the `/var/log/daemon.log` file:

```
...
...
... 
Dec 22 10:52:46 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: Using settings from "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info" (daemon.c:488)
Dec 22 10:52:46 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: Saved "/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json" (bencode.c:1731)
Dec 22 10:52:46 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: Loaded 1 torrents (session.c:1937)
Dec 22 10:53:01 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD.zip Could not connect to tracker (announcer.c:994)
Dec 22 10:53:01 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD.zip Retrying announce in 301 seconds. (announcer.c:1003)
Dec 22 10:53:01 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD.zip Could not connect to tracker (announcer.c:994)
Dec 22 10:53:01 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD.zip Retrying announce in 324 seconds. (announcer.c:1003)
Dec 22 10:53:01 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD.zip Could not connect to tracker (announcer.c:994)
...
...
...
Dec 22 12:34:29 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD.zip Starting IPv4 DHT announce (firewalled, 168 nodes) (tr-dht.c:574)
Dec 22 12:36:18 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD.zip Connection failed (announcer.c:994)
Dec 22 12:36:18 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD.zip Retrying announce in 300 seconds. (announcer.c:1003)
Dec 22 12:37:06 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD.zip IPv4 DHT announce done (tr-dht.c:542)
Dec 22 12:42:24 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD.zip Connection failed (announcer.c:994)
Dec 22 12:42:24 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD.zip Retrying announce in 910 seconds. (announcer.c:1003)
Dec 22 12:51:54 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD.zip Scrape error: Connection failed (announcer.c:1259)
Dec 22 12:51:54 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD.zip Retrying scrape in 1859 seconds. (announcer.c:1268)
Dec 22 12:58:38 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD.zip Connection failed (announcer.c:994)
Dec 22 12:58:38 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD.zip Retrying announce in 3630 seconds. (announcer.c:1003)
Dec 22 13:00:06 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD.zip Starting IPv4 DHT announce (firewalled, 168 nodes) (tr-dht.c:574)
Dec 22 13:02:58 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1904]: FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD.zip IPv4 DHT announce done (tr-dht.c:542)
```

I tried to download the file with uTorrent, on windows 8, using the same torrent file, and it works.

It seems that the `transmission` daemon cannot connect to the trackers. What am I missing?

Comment: Your issue sounds like it's being caused by your firewall. I'd try temporarily disabling it.

Comment: Check that your  port is opened: `nc -u -z ‹hostname› ‹port›` Result should be "Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port xxxxx [udp/*] succeeded!"

Comment: In order to see the success message, I had to add the `-v` (verbose) option to `nc`: `nc -v -u -z <hostname> <port>`.  That's the modified OpenBSD version of nc on Ubuntu, nc version: 1.105-7ubuntu1